# Django 1.10: Setting admin.site.site_header and using default admin login view

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to (at the project level):

- Use the default admin view (`auth.views.login`) as my login view
- Set the `admin.site.site_header` within `ulrs.py` so that it appears on the both the login and admin pages

First, doing this does update the `site_header` on the admin page...

```
# urls.py

admin.site.site_header = "my header name"

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/?', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    ...
]
```

From here it would appear I should be able to either do this:

```
# registration/login.html

{% extends "admin/login.html" %}
```

Or this (copy/paste from django/admin/templates/login.html):

```
# registration/login.html

{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% load i18n static %}

{% block extrastyle %}{{ block.super }}<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "admin/css/login.css" %}" />
{{ form.media }}
{% endblock %}
...
```

Neither employ the header with "my header name" like the admin view does.

Why doesn't my `registration/login.html` get the `admin.site.site_header` I'm setting in `urls.py`?

Thanks.

***Update:***

I see that `auth/view.py` doesn't have `site_header` in its context by default:

```
# auth/view.py

def login(...

    current_site = get_current_site(request)

    context = {
        'form': form,
        redirect_field_name: redirect_to,
        'site': current_site,
        'site_name': current_site.name,
    }

    ...
```

And that `admin/sites.py` is responsible for defining `AdminSite` which sets `site_header` for the admin site

```
class AdminSite(object):
    ...

    def each_context(self, request):
        """
        Returns a dictionary of variables to put in the template context for
        *every* page in the admin site.

        For sites running on a subpath, use the SCRIPT_NAME value if site_url
        hasn't been customized.
        """
        script_name = request.META['SCRIPT_NAME']
        site_url = script_name if self.site_url == '/' and script_name else self.site_url
        return {
            'site_title': self.site_title,
            'site_header': self.site_header,
            'site_url': site_url,
            'has_permission': self.has_permission(request),
            'available_apps': self.get_app_list(request),
        }
...
```

I see how I could create my own `base_site.html` (hardcoding `{{ "my header name }}`) to use in the copy/pasted `login.html` above, but that seems messy.  I'd like to set this variable in one place and use as much of admin directly as possible.

My high-level interest is to basically piggy-back the admin app for regular user accounts.  Am I going about this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My high-level interest is to basically piggy-back the admin app for
>   regular user accounts. Am I going about this wrong?

Unfortunately, yes, you are.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial02/

> The admin isn’t intended to be used by site visitors. It’s for site
>   managers.

It's so easy to add an authentication system using one of the many tried and tested registrion/auth packages available (example django-allauth) that trying to re-purpose django admin as a user level app is wastefull and not very secure either.

Comment: would you recommend `django-allauth` then? Also (considering your comment about "not very secure"), it seems one would want their admin to be secure... would you suggest not using the admin module?

Comment: yes django-allauth comes highly recommended. Don't use the admin for ordinary uses, build something with CBVs